# Not able to see Chrome UI for Selenium Webdriver when trigger through JENKINS

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have a Selenium Web-driver project which is working absolutely fine with passed results, the only problem is when Jenkins instantiate chrome-driver it runs in the background. So I can't the chrome driver UI going on but only able to see the end report. I am running Jenkins on Windows Server 2016. Also, tried the Jenkins process option to allow remote application.
When I triggered the same built though cmd, then I could see the ChromeDriver-UI though.
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** your jenkins job executed on same machine where your jenkins server is

If jenkins use different user to login jenkins server to run job, the browser will opened under that user, if you login with that user, you will see browser. (in most time, i guess browser opened on system user, you can open Task Manager and check Chrome process in different user)

**2)** yourjenkins job executed on slave machine which is not same as jenkins server

browser can be opened on slave machine or other machine, depends on you use RemoteDriver, Selenium Address.

But I guess you are the case **1)**

Comment: I was using My Jenkins account and logged in with my account in Server too still saw the chrome-driver in the Task Manager process not in foreground

Comment: See those chrome-driver run under which user, then login on with that user, then you can see Chrome opened during job running.  If you still not very clear what happen, you can search some document about jenkins user